# If $T\subset\mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $S \subset T$, then $\sup S \leq \sup T$ and $\inf T \leq\inf S$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S$ and $T$ be nonempty sets of $\mathbb{R}$, with $T$ a bounded set and $S \subset T$. Prove that $\sup S \leq \sup T$ and $\inf T \leq\inf S$.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: Also, you can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\inf T \le t \le \sup T$ for all $t \in T$.
Since $S \subset T$, if $s \in S$, then we have $\inf T \le s \le \sup T$. It follows that $\inf T \le \inf S$, and $\sup S \le \sup T$.